# German word for 'feeling no particular way' without negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german, difference, usage

I'm trying to hunt down a word I can't seem to find anywhere. In English the feeling would be put 'feeling no particular way,' or simply existing with emphasis. Emptiness isn't the right meaning, as it has negative connotation. Perhaps Leeresamkeit? Leerefreude?

Comment: I'd simply say "ich bin O.K." ;-).

Comment: [Ich will hier nur sitzen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqCg1IQ2DWY) ;)

Comment: Kann nicht meckern, tue Ich trotzdem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you're looking for might be [*Ausgeglichenheit*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ausgeglichenheit) or as an adjective/adverb *ausgeglichen*.

It doesn't carry any connotation in one or the other direction: the scale is balanced, not going up or down on one or the other side.

In English *Ausgeglichenheit* would be something like *balance, calmness, even temper*.

- ein *ausgeglichener* Mensch
- Dem Ehrgeizigen mangelt es an innerer *Ausgeglichenheit*.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Definitely not. *Ausgeglichen* doesn't imply any source, root or cause. It just states *no strong feelings* in one or the other direction. See also [wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=Ausgeglichenheit&title=Special%3ASearch&ns0=1).

Comment: @mkrieger1 *Ausgeglichenheit* "inner balance" is mostly a state, not a trait. The trait is *Gleichmut* "equanimity".

Answer (score 12):

I propose *[gleichmütig](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gleichm%C3%BCtig)*, if you want an adjective. It literally means "of equal or balanced temper".

Comment: I like your answer. The noun "Gleichmut" also exists, but isn't used that much, and you could also use "Gleichmütigkeit".
It's definitly "positive" - it is something many people strife for, to not be affected that much by the punches life throws at you.

Comment: This is a very uncommon word, I actually had to look up its meaning. And even now, I cannot quite get rid of the feeling that it's something negative (which, by its definition, it isn't!), maybe because it sounds so similar to "gleichgültig"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If you are unfamiliar with that word and had to look up its meaning, then your associations for it don't stem from your familiarity with that word but from other words that sound or look similar and have little to do with the word at hand. I have all kinds of feelings when I encounter an unfamiliar word, but that does not mean that my feelings are in any way indicative of what that word means to someone familiar with it. Just because, for example, *gleichgültig* and *gleichmütig* begin with the same prefix, doesn't mean both evoke the same negative association. [contd.]

Comment: @O.R.Mapper [contd.] That would be like saying *Überraschung* has a negative connotation because of *Überfall* or *Verzeihung* because of *Vergewaltigung*. If you don't know a word you don't know a word and aren't a reliable source for its usage and meaning. —— This reminds me of the fact that Goethe knew 93,000 words while the average German speaker knows around 12,000 to 16,000 words. I suspect there are many more words you aren't familiar with.

Answer (score 9):

It is hard to find a word that will never carry a negative connotation, because there are situations where indifference is not considered socially acceptable. In those situations any word expressing that one has no particular feeling towards the matter in question will have a negative connotation.

That being said, there are two nouns meaning "indifference":  *Gleichgültigkeit* and *Indifferenz*. They do not carry a negative connotation per se. *Indifferenz* is from a somewhat upper register, so it might sound a little formal. The corresponding adjectives are *gleichgültig* and *indifferent*. If you are looking for adjectives, there is also *egal*, describing something that does not matter. Example sentences are:

- *Es ist mir gleichgültig.*
- *Ich bin in dieser Frage indifferent.*
- *Es ist mir egal.*

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few phrases which come to my mind as a native speaker, without any sources or references, which would serve as an answer to "how are you?"

- "Alles wie immer"
- "Alles entspannt"
- "Nichts Besonderes los"
- "Alles O.K."

All phrases have in common that nothing special has happened, neither good nor bad, and no nagging problems are present. A bit like the absence of the anecdotal Chinese curse "may you live in interesting times".

Comment: Answer to an enquiry, 'keine Ahnung! "

Answer (score -2):

"Ambivalent" is the same word in German, and I believe it's a relatively neutral term.

Comment: Ambivalent does not imply "no particular way" but rather indecision between two options.

Comment: Actually *ambivalent* means "wanting two options at the same time and being torn between them". That is neither neutral nor is it usually considered positive.